# I want to assign lot numbers to particular rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

My table structure is

```
BatchID|BatchName|StartDate|NoOfTrainee|LotNo
```

I want to sort the table according StartDate and assign batch numbers accordingly.

1st lot number will be assigned to a batch when the number of trainees reach a minimum of 100. 
Eg:

```
BatchId|BatchName|StartDate|NoOfTrainee|LotNo
1|  mum1|   2015-06-01| 25| NULL
2|  del2|   2015-06-01| 30| NULL
3|  cal1|   2015-06-02| 35| NULL
4|  bang1|  2015-06-02| 20| NULL
5|  bang2|  2015-06-03| 40| NULL
6|  del1|   2015-06-05| 30| NULL
7|  mum2|   2015-06-06| 25| NULL
```

Rows 1,2,3,4 will be assigned lot 1 because their sum reached 100.
Next 100 trainees will be assigned lot number 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` and `SUM OVER()` to achieve what you need like this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY StartDate,BatchName) BatchId,
BatchName, StartDate, NoOfTrainee,
CEILING(SUM(NoOfTrainee) OVER(ORDER BY StartDate,BatchName) / 100.0) as LotNo
FROM BatchTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ef51/8)